# node.js: is there no way to put HTML into i18n-node JSON translation files?

Tags: html, node.js, anchor, sails.js, i18n-node

The question says it all.  If I put HTML directly into the (JSON-formatted) translation file, like this:

```
"test_html" : "click <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>here</a>",
```

I get this in my HTML:

```
click &lt;a href=&#39;http://stackoverflow.com/&#39;&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;
```

I also tried combining this in my translation file:

```
"test_html_placeholder" : "click %shere%s",
```

With this in my HTML:

```
<%= __('test_html_placeholder', '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">', '</a>') %>
```

But got similar results.

The only thing I can get to work is this clumsiness:

```
"test_html_pre" : "click ",
"test_html_link" : "here",
"test_html_post" : ".",
```

with this:

```
<%= __('test_html_pre') %><a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><%= __('test_html_link') %></a><%= __('test_html_post') %>
```

But it's so cumbersome as to be almost not worth doing, and moreover the word order in some languages would force me to put some empty strings in my translation files, which i18n-node doesn't seem to like as it spits out the key (attribute) name when it 
encounters an empty string.

I also tried using "\" as an escape character in front of the symbols, but I got an invalid JSON error when I lifted sails (restarted the server).

Any ideas, workarounds?  I'm using sails.js, it wasn't my decision but I'm stuck with it and it comes with i18n-node.  It's kind of late in the day on this project to consider using another library, but not completely out of the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

beside of any upcoming discussion whether to include (html-)code in language files or not:

try to use

```
<%- __('<a href="#">click</a>') %>
```

instead of

```
<%= __('<a href="#">click</a>') %>
```

in ejs (the sails default template engine) a '<%=' will escape any html tags while '<%-' puts output as is without touching it. I am pretty sure you'll find unescaped html in your .json files. i18n doesn't do any transformation other than `JSON.stringify()` but almost all template engines do escape strings by default to prevent xssi.

Comment: "beside of any upcoming discussion whether to include (html-)code in language files or not:"You seem to be hinting it's a bad idea for other reasons, presumably maintainability?  Does out-of-the-box sails give me some other way of keeping HTML out of my language files?

Comment: of course this opinionated, but as rule of thumb I use languages files only for short and complete phrases and try to separate them from context. Next larger phrases go in partials or even up to separated views. But: to just translate `"click <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>here</a>"` I'd break my own rules too :)

Comment: @jasper Did you ever solve this? That is, find a solution other than the "hack" you mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 2):

For those using pug/jade, you can use

```
!{ __('key_for_your_text') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for pug is using

```
p!= __('key_for_your_text')
```